# How I can calculate the switching frequency of an SCR and replacing diode with SCR in boost converter?

Tags: frequency, switching, scr

I want to find the switching frequency of SCR. I want to use an SCR or a GTO thyristor so I can use a switching frequency up to 20 kHz, but as I am new so I am unable to find the SCR frequency from its data sheet.

Comment: The switching frequency is "dependant" on HOW it is used ... So, a "schematic" is necessary, because when it is "fired", by itself,  it can't stop conducting.

Comment: Ok, I forgot ... for the SCR. :-)

Comment: Hi Antonio, I know it will sound bit awkard to you but I want to replace the diode of simple boost converter with SCR. This is because I am try to make a fault tolerant circuit for boost converter. Now, I do know that once it is on it will not turn off, but that will not be a problem for me, as I want to keep it on and once I will replace the component, automatically SCR will be off as holding current goes to zero once I shutdown the converter. Now so far, I trying to find out a SCR which can work on 20Khz frequency.

Comment: Ok, what you should know is, at least, the max direct current, as stated in an answer, to evaluate the turn-on and turn-off times ... because an important data is the "di/dt".

Answer (score 1):

You could derive the switching frequency from the turn-on and turn-off times in the data sheet, but whatever it is you're trying to do there must be a better way. If you describe your application, you'll be swamped with helpful suggestions.

If you want to replace diode D
[image]

Image source: [Wikipedia - Buck converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter)

then, depending on the specific SCR chosen, several different things might happen. If the SCR has a short turn-off time, it would actually turn off every switching cycle and need to be triggered again. You might also be exceeding the reverse cathode to gate voltage limit depending on the output voltage and the trigger circuit. The manufacturers that do specify the limit say 5 volts - the same as the emitter to base breakdown limit on transistors. If your switching frequency has a period less than the turn-off time of the SCR then the result would be unpredictable. The SCR will turn off while the switch is closed, but maybe not long enough to stay so.

There is no obvious way that changing the diode for an SCR will make the circuit more fault tolerant, even if you found one with very fast turn-on and turn-off times.

Comment: Hi Stretch, I want to replace the diode of simple boost converter with SCR. This is because I am try to make a fault tolerant circuit for boost converter. Now, I do know that once it is on it will not turn off, but that will not be a problem for me, as I want to keep it on and once I will replace the component, automatically SCR will be off as holding current goes to zero once I shutdown the converter. Now so far, I trying to find out a SCR which can work on 20Khz frequency.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for a well-explained answer. I am using a boost converter to charge the 36-volt battery. In this boost converter, I am replacing the diode D with MOSFET first. In case, if MOSFET fails under any fault condition, then I still have an extra SCR which can provide the path to charge the battery. The switching frequency is 100Khz.

Comment: As you said in your answer, SCR will be off when the switch is on and triggered again, do you mean that I need to give it a gate signal like MOSFET? like a PWM signal so that it will turn it on again because I thought SCR will turn off and on and I just need to give a constant 5 volts at the gate. Pardon, if I am saying anything wrong.